# adding icon to the active class than just colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i want to add a play button icon when clicking on the link, i.e. not only the active class with colour is applied but an icon of play button appears next to it. below is my code so far. i'm not exactly sure why there's an error on the javascript bit on this site, but the code does work on my wordpress site. i just want to add in the .active not just the colour but  a play button icon to appear next to it too. cheers.

```js
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.selector a').click(function() {
        $('.selector a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
.selector {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.selector li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.selector li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.selector li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=selector>
  <li><a class="active" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aBihWjWQdvA" target="test" onclick="document.getElementById('test').frameBorder=1"> 1 </a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aBihWjWQxvd" target="test" onclick="document.getElementById('test').frameBorder=1"> 2 </a></li>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aBihWjWQxvA" frameborder="0" name="test" id="test" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:90%;height:90%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

What about using `:before` pseudo selector?

https://jsfiddle.net/arfeo/g3wmdn4u/3/

```
...

.selector {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.selector li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.selector li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.selector li a:before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 5px;
}


.selector li a.active:before {
  content: '▶';
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.selector li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
}

...
```

Comment: hey Arefo, thanks for your response. but i want the play icon to appear when clicking on the link and not to be already present on both the links. for example when you click on say link  1, the play icon appears " suggesting the video is playing" if that makes sense

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly, but do i need to include this part of the code though; .selector li a:after {
    content: '';
    margin-left: 5px;
}

Comment: @website_noob_123 sorry, I did not understand the question

Comment: the line .selector li a:before, is that necessary?, doesn't .selector li a.active:before do the job?

Comment: also ive tried adding a different icon instead of the play button you used but it doesnt work i used   content:"\f015;
    font-family:"Fontawesome";
    margin-right: 5px;

Comment: @website_noob_123 yes, `.selector li a:before` is not necessary. I left it only for visual understanding of what is doing over here. As about your modifications: `content:"\f015` is wrong, it should be `content:'\f015'`.